# ETAS model initial parameter determining

Tags: r, point-process, spatio-temporal

I am trying to fit a spatio-temporal epidemic type after schock model to an Earthquake catologue using ETAS package R. However, I do not know about it too much. Without good initial parameter set the algorithm diverges. I have not found anything in the documentation of the package and in literature about it? How can I set initial parameter set for spatio temporal ETAS model? The question is a general question dependent of the algorithm that the package use I think.